# Can I get JavaScript function's information in htmlunit?

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm not good at English, so I use a translator to post. Please understand if there are any strange parts of the article. I am currently using htmlunit to create a program that changes JavaScript and runs it. When a specific JavaScript is executed, I want to change it to a different JavaScript function, but I have not received information on the function. For example, it is as follows.

```
// crawling page
<button onclick="movePage('a', b);">AAA</button>

// in htmlunit (I want this information)
function name : movePage
function parameter : 'a', b
function parameter count : 2
function result : 'new page url'
```

like this

Can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

At least you can intercept the response (e.g. the one delivering the js code) and replace the function by a different implementation.

https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse